# Control the duration of character

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a problem with `libgdx`.

I want to have a control of the duration of the character position exactly 2 seconds and after 2 seconds, the character changes the position and repeat the process again...

This is my code:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    carte();
    counterTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    time += delta;
    if(counterTime > 2 ) {// each second ==> one call to position random

        position = new Vector2(this.mari.x, this.mari.y);
        counterTime =0;


        /************* position.x & position.y   is a position random of array(carte)*****************/

        batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(time), position.x, position.y, 64, 64);


        animation.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);

    }
    batch.end();
}

///and i have been initializ the position in the cerate() methode
```

Any idea?

Comment: You have many options for this. If you are using `Stage` and `Actor`s you could use their `Action`s. Create a `RepeatAction` with a `DelayAction`, which gets your desired move. You could also use Libgdx `Timer` for your needs. Or you can also sum up `delta` in each `render` and when it reaches 2, do your move and reset `delta`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    carte();
    elapsedTime+= System.currentTimeMilis()-initialTime;
    if(elapsedTime >= 2000) {
        position = new Vector2(this.mari.x, this.mari.y);
        batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(time), position.x, position.y, 64, 64);
        animation.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
        elapsedTime=0;
        initialTime=System.currentTimeMilis();

    }
    batch.end();
}
```

- Create and initialize initialTime (with System.currentTimeMilis()) on create().
- Create and initialize elapsedTime (With elapsedTime=0) on create().

Ask if you have any question :)

**EDIT:** Just realized of a couple improvements (I´m not editing code though, let me explain):

1) `batch` should stay open as little time as possible.
Unless `carte()` uses (draws something) `batch`, I would consider:

```
batch.begin();
batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(time), position.x, position.y, 64, 64);
batch.end();
```

(Leaving batch open just enough to draw).

2) 
Instead of:

```
elapsedTime+= System.currentTimeMilis()-initialTime;
    if(elapsedTime >= 2000) {
```

You can use: (a bit faster)

```
if(System.currentTimeMilis()-initialTime >= 2000) {
```